# Predicting therapy response from categorical variables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, predictive-models, treatment-effect

We have a dataset of about 200 patients that have been diagnosed with a lung disease. At the time of diagnosis, their lung capacity was characterized by various parameters, all of them measured on a continuous scale. After 1 1/2 years of treatment, the lung capacity was characterized again by the same parameters.

We are now trying to identify factors that may help predict whether or not lung capacity might either improve, remain or even worsen after the treatment. These factors are mainly binary (e.g. mutation present/not present), while some of them such as age are also on a continuous scale.

We have now been wondering which kind of statistical approach might be most appropriate to solve the question at hand, while different ideas have been tried:

- One idea was to calculate the differences in lung capacity before and after treatment and use a Mann-Whitney test to compare them within several categorical variables.
- Furthermore, we binned the differences in lung capacity response into different response groups, such as “worse”, “unaltered”, and “better”. Afterwards, we compared the categories “worse” vs. “unaltered/better” as well as “better” vs. “unaltered/worse” across several categories with a chi-square to identify which categories are associated with a “worse” or “better” response, respectively.
- Finally, we used the same kind of categorisation (“worse” vs. “unaltered/better” as well as “better” vs. “unaltered/worse”) as dependent variables and calculated the odds ratios of different independent variables using logistic regression.

Next to correcting for multiple testing, I have been wondering if these are valid approaches to try and solve the problem at hand, or if there are other, more suitable tests/approaches that should be used. Any help would be much appreciated!